# How to name a module without conflict with variable name?

Tags: python

I found sometime it's difficult to name a module without conflicting with a variable name latter. For example, I have a following class:

```
class Petition(object):
    def __init__(self, signature_count_requirement):
        self._signature_count_requirement = signature_count_requirement
```

and a following function:

```
def check_if_someone_can_sponsor_a_petition(someone):
    pass
```

so it's nature to write code like this:

```
if check_if_someone_can_sponsor_a_petition(a):
    petition = Petition(3)
```

Then I want to put the function and the `Petition` class into a module. Now what should I call the module? It seems nature to name the module `petition`. However it's very easy to conflict with variable names latter like this:

```
import petition
if petition.check_if_someone_can_sponsor_a_petition(a):
    petition = petition.Petition(3)  # this is ugly.
```

The `datetime` module could be a better(worse?) example. When came across with name `datetime` in code, I often had to make sure it's the module or the class name or someone's variable name.

Is there any good conventions about how to name a module to avoid conflict with a variable name latter?

Comment: You can change the name of the imported module like that `import petition as m_petition`

Comment: @julivico thanks. it's a good habit I think. One of the answers below suggested the same thing. Next time I import `datetime` I'd like to import `datetime` as `m_datetime`. But this require the people who import the module to pay a attention. But people often make mistakes so I think to better to solve this problem by naming the module in a better way.

Comment: The key is to exploit namespaces to your advantage. Let's consider `requests`. One may argue that `get` or `post` are ambiguous names, but at the end of the day, by using namespaces it results in clean, concise and self-explaining invocations of `requests.get(url)`.

Comment: It's a very good question. I run into this daily. However there's no good solution and any solution is a matter of opinion. StackOverflow is not the right place to ask this. I would like this asked somewhere else, but I'm not sure where. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html

Comment: @qarma I agree that StackOverflow is not the right place to ask this. But like you said, I'm not sure where to ask and people on StackOverflow are so experienced with coding so I think I can get my answer here. So far I think I can use the `import as` to avoid namespace conflicts myself.

Comment: OT: `check_if_someone_can_sponsor_a_petition` should be renamed. Start with usage (i.e. call site), it could be e.g. `petition.can_be_sponsored(...)` (better, but what is "can be"), thus `petition.is_sponsored(...)` and `petition.is_valid(...)` the latter means "follows rules, ergo e.g. can be sponsored in theory"... You could go OOP where `petition` is an object, that has properties like `.valid` and `.sponsored` and maybe some methods.

Answer (score 3):

Your code wouldn't actually work, because assigning to the local variable `petition` means Python will treat all references to that name as local, so won't find the global reference which is to the module, causing a NameError.

You can import the module with a different name:

```
 import petition as petition_module
```

Or you can import the things you need directly:

```
 from petition import Petition, check_if_someone_can_sponsor_a_petition
```

For more clean up you might consider making check_if_someone_can_sponsor_a_petition a classmethod of Petition.

Comment: Yes, the example is trying to show the name like `petition` is prone to error  so I want a better name.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use such qualified names if you don't want to. For example, calling your module `petitions` you might write

```
from petitions import Petition, check_if_someone_can_sponsor_a_petition
```

This copies the names into your local namespace, so it's then OK to write stuff like

```
if check_if_someone_can_sponsor_a_petition(a):
    petition = Petition(3)  # this is no longer so ugly.
```

Of course if you were instead to call your module `petition` it would be a very bad idea to then have a variable of the same name ...

Comment: This, and the method `import petition as pet` both can solve the problem. But it requires the people who import the module to pay a attention. But people often make mistakes so I want a better name to avoid that. Maybe name the module `m_petition` directly?

Comment: The person importing the module always has to be aware of potential namespace conflicts. A number of solutions are available, the most helpful of which (since you appear to want to use fully-qualified names) is to import the module under a suitable alias, using `import module_real_name as alias`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it anwsers your question, but you can import your module with the '**as**' directive to define the local name of your choice for the module:

```
import petition as pet

if pet.check_if_someone_can_sponsor_a_petition(a):
        petition = pet.Petition(3)
```

This may solve your name conflict.

Comment: Thank you, it's a good habit I think. But like I said in other answers, it requires the people who import the module to pay a attention and people often make mistakes so I'm thinking name the module `m_petition` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Class names should be written with the CapsWords convention, variables all lower case, functions lower case with underscores. I think alot of people use a trailing underscore to avoid naming confilcts. It might be ugly but this is the convention as of PEP 8. See the link below for the section on Naming Conventions.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions

Hope this helps!